# ASP .NET MVC 3 routes to implement a "coming soon" page functionality, hiding certain areas and controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

The page I am no implementing is in a "coming soon" stage. Some elements are not available yet, except for the informative part.
I need to make navigation to a 'ClientPanel' area and the Account controller impossible through defining a "ComingSoon" route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ComingSoon",
            "General/Home/ComingSoon");
```

The default route I'm using is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{*catchall}",
            new { area = "General", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "WebAccess.Areas.General.Controllers" }).DataTokens.Add("area", "General");
```

I need two routes to lead to the "Coming Soon" page:

```
"General/Account/{action}/{id}/{*catchall}"
```

and

```
"ClientPanel/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

How can I achieve that?

I need to point out that I have tried using Route Magic to do:

```
routes.Redirect(r => r.MapRoute("ClientPanel", "ClientPanel/{controller}/{action}/{id}")).To(comingSoon);
```

but even though Glimpse tells me that the ClientPanel route has been matched correctly, the page still goes to the ClientPanel area.

Comment: For ClientPanel and Account controller route (in MapRoute) have you tried setting up controller as Home and action as ComminSoon?   `new { area = "General", controller = "Home", action = "ComingSoon", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`  ?